# How to disable win32 'interface' macro?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm going absolutely nuts here. I'm doing some C++ development on Windows and I have a namespace named 'interface':

```
namespace gd {
namespace interface {

}} // end namespace
```

However, there is a file named "objbase.h" that gets included no matter if I include "Windows.h" or "Wtypes.h", which contains a macro named 'interface'. This macro won't allow me to use the namespace name. Is there a feature in the Win32 API to disable the definition of the interface macro? If not, can someone think of a clever workaround to disabling it, without requiring too many mass changes in my code base?

Comment: @delnan I've thought of a wrapper include that does that for me, but if someone outside of my code (it's a library) uses windows.h directly, they will run into the same problem. It'd be a lot easier to disable it at the API level with some preprocessor definition

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you really want to do this, you could `#undef` the `interface` macro.

I'd suggest, rather, not naming your namespace `interface`, since `interface` is as close to being a reserved word as you can get without actually being a reserved word. It's going to cause a great deal of confusion to have that namespace in use.

Comment: Thanks, I have renamed the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you could also define [`WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040133/what-does-defining-win32-lean-and-mean-exclude-exactly) to avoid that `objbase.h` gets pulled in when including `windows.h`.