# Windows header file <Windows.h> with WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

Tags: windows, winapi

```
#include <Windows.h>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
```

Why the above code statement has mistake? Is the order wrong or others?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Windows.h header, if WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN is not defined, the preprocessor will includes other headers. So if you want to not include theses headers, you must define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN before #include , else it won't have any effects

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <cderr.h>
#include <dde.h>
#include <ddeml.h>
#include <dlgs.h>
#ifndef _MAC
    #include <lzexpand.h>
    #include <mmsystem.h>
    #include <nb30.h>
    #include <rpc.h>
#endif
#include <shellapi.h>
#ifndef _MAC
    #include <winperf.h>
    #include <winsock.h>
#endif
#ifndef NOCRYPT
    #include <wincrypt.h>
    #include <winefs.h>
    #include <winscard.h>
#endif

#ifndef NOGDI
    #ifndef _MAC
        #include <winspool.h>
        #ifdef INC_OLE1
            #include <ole.h>
        #else
            #include <ole2.h>
        #endif /* !INC_OLE1 */
    #endif /* !MAC */
    #include <commdlg.h>
#endif /* !NOGDI */
#endif /* WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN */
```

Directly from Windows.h

Comment: How should I write if I just want the header files below be excluded? 
#include <cderr.h>
#include <dde.h>
#include <ddeml.h>
#include <dlgs.h>

Comment: define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN before Windows.h and add what you wants to include manually (don't forget Windows.h).

Comment: So, by using #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN, all the above header files will exclude. If you want some header files back, just #include back before #include <windows.h>. Am I right?

Answer (score 4):

The order is wrong.  `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` affects what `windows.h` declares, so it needs to be defined before `windows.h` is included:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
```

Comment: Good answer, just for future [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040133/what-does-defining-win32-lean-and-mean-exclude-exactly)