# SHGetKnownFolderPath: ambiguous symbol 'IServiceProvider'?

Tags: c++-cli, known-folders

I'm trying to create a folder for my app in `/AppData/local` so that i can save some ini files in it, i tried to get the Destination path using:

```
#include <ShlObj.h>

if (SHGetKnownFolderPath (FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, NULL, &tempPath) == S_OK)
{
....
}
```

It doesn't work and gives me these errors:

```
Error   1   error C2872: 'IServiceProvider' : ambiguous symbol  c:\program files\windows kits\8.0\include\um\ocidl.h    6482    1   Project2
Error   2   error C2872: 'IServiceProvider' : ambiguous symbol  C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\shobjidl.h 9181    1   Project2
```

I tried adding `#pragma comment (lib, "Shell32.lib")` and linking the `Shell32.lib` in the project settings and nothing changed.

The errors disappear when i remove `#include <ShlObj.h>` but then the `SHGetKnownFolderPath` function becomes undefined. How can i fix this?

**Note:** I'm on Windows 7

**Edit:** My Project Header files are:

#### MyForm.h

```
#pragma once

#define CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include "gamepad.h"
#include "configure.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <Dbt.h>

namespace Project2 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::Diagnostics;

    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this->gamepad = gcnew Gamepad();
            this->SETTINGS = gcnew Settings();
        }
        ....
    };
}
```

#### gamepad.h

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
extern "C"
{
#include <hidsdi.h>
}
#include "InputHandler.h"
#include "keycodes.h"

using namespace System;

public ref class Gamepad
{
    ....
}
```

#### configure.h

```
#pragma once

#include "keycodes.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>
#include <msclr\marshal.h>


using namespace System;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace msclr::interop;

public ref class Settings
{
public:
    Settings(void)
    {
        PWSTR tempPath;
        if (SUCCEEDED (SHGetKnownFolderPath (FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, NULL, &tempPath)))
            Debug::WriteLine (gcnew String (tempPath));
        else Debug::WriteLine ("Failed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IServerProvider` is indeed ambiguous, it exists both as an COM interface type in the servprov.h Windows SDK header file *and* as .NET interface type in the System namespace.

Simplest way to repro your problem is to put the *using namespace* directive in the wrong spot:

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  using namespace System;
  #include <ShlObj.h>
```

Bam, 18 errors.  No problemo if you order them right:

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include <ShlObj.h>
  using namespace System;
```

Careful with those *using* directives, they are really good at creating ambiguity.

Comment: Please check my updated question to see my header files, i moved `configure.h` in `MyForm.h` to the top and the errors disappeared. is this because i have `System` `using` directive in `gamepad.h`?

Comment: Sure, that does it.  Having a `using namespace` directive in a .h file is always a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

`IServerProvider` is ambiguous because it is a COM interface type in servprov.h (which you get with windows.h) and as a .NET interface type in the System namespace.

If you don't need all the APIs in windows.h, you can [`#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11040133/1339280) to get a subset that excludes the `IServiceProvider` definition and avoids the ambiguity.

Do the `#define` before the `#include` and it's probably a good idea to `#undef` afterward, like this:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#undef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
```