# How can I clear console to the right of the cursor in Windows NT command prompt with C++?

Tags: c++

I need an output on the same line, like this:

```
std::cout << "\rIt's " << leisure << " time!";
```

I want to make sure I do not see stuff like `time!e!` at the end of the line if the next value of `leisure` is shorter. `\t` does not overwrite the symbols (if run from cmd), so I still see `time!e!`. `\033[0K` is a *VT 100* escape sequence and is not supported by Windows NT. What is the best way to solve the problem and make it as crossplatform as possible?

Comment: Try adding trailing spaces after the !

Comment: Which version of Windows NT are you talking about? For example, Windows 10 does support [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences).

Comment: @cup the dumbest but honestly for now it seems the most crossplatform solution

Comment: @heapunderrun I have win 10 but enabling the option you've offered seems a complicated procedure

Comment: Standard C++ I/O streams do not support what you are asking for. For more complex output, use a 3rd party ncurses library instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to avoid additional coding for a single line terminator, but since there is seemingly no other solution, I resorted to [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) as suggested in the comments:

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>


static const bool enable_VT_mode(void) {
    HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (hOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return false;

    DWORD dwMode = 0;
    if (!GetConsoleMode(hOut, &dwMode)) return false;

    dwMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
    if (!SetConsoleMode(hOut, dwMode)) return false;

    return true;
}


const std::string get_terminator(void) noexcept {
    if (enable_VT_mode()) return "\x1b[0K";
    else return "                        ";
}
```

Then go like this:

```
static const std::string terminator = get_terminator();

std::cout << "\rIt's " << leisure << " time!" << terminator;
```

As suggested, I added `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` to exclude unnecessary stuff from `windows.h`

Comment: You might want to add #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN before <windows.h>  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11040230/2041317